# Decoding with NSCoding: Does Value Exist For Key?

Tags: objective-c, nscoding

When using NSCoding and decoding values, is there a way to tell if a value exists for a given key?  In other words, what I'm trying to do is...

```
if([decoder valueExistsForKey:@"myKey"])   //valueExistsForKey is not a real method :(
{
    NSInteger *myInt = [decoder decodeValueForKey:@"myKey"];
}
else
{
    //handle special case
}
```

The issue is that I have old versions of documents in my app that don't have the "myKey" value, and if they don't have it, using 0 for myInt (what happens if you decode a nonexistent key) is not the behavior I want.  However, I can't just decode and check if myInt == 0, because it might legitimately be equal to 0.

Since the valueExistsForKey method does not seem to exist, how can I replicate this behavior?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about [`containsValueForKey`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCoder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCoder/containsValueForKey:)?

Comment: Derp. Thanks haha.  I knew I was missing something, it seemed like the functionality I wanted was pretty standard functionality...